# How to print to specific column in a CSV from perl script

Tags: perl, csv

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
Config,name,sub,produce,negative,positive,dying
RDF-12,jakl,xol,12,4,2,4
```

In my perl script, I have following variables:

```
$config = 'LSF-13'
$produce = 34;
$positive = 6;
$dying = 3;
```

I am missing variables for the columns 'name', 'sub', and 'negative' but still want to place(append) my variables in their respective columns.

```
$file = "/lsd/filepath/text.csv";
open $fh, '>>', $file or warn "can't open";
print $fh $config, $produce, $positive, $dying;
```

My code is not allowing me to specify the columns I want to match with my variable however.

Desired Output:

```
Config,name,sub,produce,negative,positive,dying
RDF-12,jakl,xol,12,4,2,4
LSF-13,,,34,,6,3
```

Comment: Can you just add blank values using `undef` for the fields that are missing?  `$config, undef, undef, $produce, undef, $positive, $dying`

Comment: What is your desired output? (How does `LSF-13` get "appended" to the `Config` field ... like `RDF-12 LSF-13` ...?

Comment: @zdim Edited a desired output section

Comment: Well `say $fh $config, ',', ',', $produce ...` (etc).  But, isn't there more to it? What if you have more lines to add, how do you designate variables (hash with column names?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Text::CSV;

my %row = (
  Config => 'LSF-13', # keys must match the case of the columns in your CSV exactly
  produce => 34,
  positive => 6,
  dying => 3,
);
my $file = "/lsd/filepath/text.csv";

# open to read the existing column names from the first line
open my $readfh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({eol => $/, binary => 1, auto_diag => 2});
$csv->column_names($csv->getline($readfh));
close $readfh;

# open to append a new line
open my $writefh, '>>:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";
$csv->print_hr($writefh, \%row);
```